# jQuery find if a dynamic generated <p> have text

Tags: jquery, text

I try to find if a dynamic created `<p>` have text. `'.layer'+count` returns my

class but I can not get it to work with .lenght.

```
if ( ($('.layer'+count).text()).length > 0 ){
alert ('I have text')
}
```

Any tips on making this work?
Thanx

Comment: Also, it appears you are using the CSS class attribute to give your paragraphs unique IDs.  This is not good.  Use the id attribute for that -- lookups are much faster. The class attribute should be used to indicate that a number of elements are part of the same group.

Comment: @James - Thanx, Ill keep in mind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( ($('.layer'+count).text().length ) > 0 )
{
    alert ('I have text')
}
```

In your code the paranthesis order was not the right one. It should  be

```
($('.layer'+count).text().length)
```

and not

```
($('.layer'+count).text()).length
```

Actually there is no need of the extra `(`. You can simply write

```
if ( $('.layer'+count).text().length > 0 )
{
    alert ('I have text')
}
```

Comment: I just tried it out in firebug and it works fine with the surrounding parentheses

Comment: It looks that it works if I do the following: if ( $('.layer'+count).text().length > 1 )

For every letter in the text the $('.layer'+count).text().length the value is incremented by 1.

So it works.
Thanx for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The extra parenthesis aren't needed around `$('.layer'+count).text()` but it should work nevertheless. Are you absolutely sure you selector matches the element? You can test that by using `alert($('.layer'+count).length)`, that would alert the amount of elements matched.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you do:

```
alert($('.layer'+count).text())
```

Comment: It gets my text if any or it gets no text